# How to circumnavigate an administrative filter

Tags: filter

My android device (Samsung s20fe) has had an administrative filter called "MbSmart" installed via a USB cable to the device which restricts certain settings, like uninstalling the software and resetting the phone, and block certain apps at their discretion as well as being able to view my network activity. Is there a way to get around this without a factory reset?

Comment: If its hardware, a factory reset isnt going to work either,

Comment: The factory reset button in the device settings is restricted. I would have to do it manually. Thus leading me to believe that a factory reset would clean the device.

Comment: You don't get answers because it is too generic. What administrative filter software are you talking about? What does it restrict? Why can't you uninstall it yourself? What have you tried to uninstall or deactivate it?